How to open a link in a browser from inside a webview in React?
I made an app in React that has Google OAuth but since it isn't supported on webviews I get "Error 403: Disallowed User Agent" when opening on in app browsers.
Is there anyway I can make a link open in a browser when clicking on it from webview (so I can just add a redirect link when userAgent is detected as webview) ?
I tried this code when userAgent is webView
<div className="webview-div">Detected you are using a webview. Google does not support OAuth in WebViews. Please open the link in a browser.
<a href="link-to-my-site.com" onclick="window.open(this.href, '_blank')"> LINK </a>
</div>

But it just opens in the webview itself and I'm left at thae same page again.

You can try this:


import React from 'react';

function MyComponent() {
  const isWebView = /WebView/.test(navigator.userAgent);

  const handleAuthClick = () => {
    if (isWebView) {
      // Open authorization URL in external browser
      window.open('https://your-oauth-authorization-url.com', '_blank');
    } else {
      // Handle authorization flow within the app
      // (e.g., initiate OAuth flow with your library of choice)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {isWebView && (
        <div className="webview-div">
          Detected you are using a webview. Google does not support OAuth in WebViews.
          Please open the link in a browser.
          <button onClick={handleAuthClick}>Authorize</button>
        </div>
      )}
      {!isWebView && (
        <div>
          {/* Render authorization button or link for non-webview environments */}
          <button onClick={handleAuthClick}>Authorize</button>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyComponent;



Hope it will help you!!

Thanks for the help but this doesn't work either

what is error or anything on above code you are facing?

There's no error. When I click on the link it just opens in the same webview browser. So now I just display a message saying the user is in a webview and needs to open the site in a browser.
